# how to create javascript dom document from a page response text and get the body content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Please help me how to create javascript dom from response text, the response text will be like:

```
<html>
<head >
//scripts and meta tags are available
</head>
<body>
//body content will have html code.
</body>
</html>
```

I used the below code to create the dom doc:

```
var parser = new DOMParser();
var xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(responsetext,"text/xml");
```

from the doc when i try to get the body content with `xmlDoc.body.innerHTML` it
gives null, but the response text have the proper data.

Please help me to get the body content.

-Raja

Answer (score 1):

You tagged this question with jQuery, so I assume you would be open to a jQuery solution?

```
$(responsetext);
```

This will give you a jQuery object refering to just the contents of the body element, so `$('<html><body><h1>title</h1></body></html>')` gives you a jQuery object referring to a new `<h1>title</h1>` element.

Also, where are you getting `responsetext` from? I assume it's an AJAX request? Why not use jQuery's ajax functionality and handle the response text in the callback?

Comment: updatePageBody = function(html, objId){
 console.log(html);
 displayDraft(html, objId);
} the above is the one method in my call back. In that html i tried the same like the below alert($html.find("body").html()); .this returns null.but the html is having proper data.

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite understand. Are you saying that `updatePageBody` is your callback for the AJAX request? And that within `displayDraft` you tried `alert($html.find("body").html());`? Where does the variable `$html` come from? It would probably help if you posted more of your code in the question.

Comment: Spycho: I couldn't use your answer code: why is "$('<html><body><h1>title</h1></body></html>').find('body')" of length 0 ? jQuery would not parse the responseText ?

Comment: Ah, jQuery parses that string and creates only the elements inside the body tag, not the whole html tag. So `$('<html><body><h1>title</h1></body></html>')` gives you a jQuery object referring to a new `<h1>title</h1>` element. This means that `$(responsetext)` should be all you need.

Answer (score 0):

Just set the innerHTML of your DOMNode to the responseText

Comment: i need only the body content but i tried from the doc i got the empty body when i tried like the below var xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(responsetext,"text/xml");xmlDoc.body.innerHTML

Comment: var xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(responsetext,"text/xml"); i am getting only empty body when i use the below

Comment: You could append it, then find the body, remove everything and re-append just the body. Or you can use jQuery to traverse the response text and append everything in the body like $("#yournnode").append($(responseText).find("body").html());